# How to loop translate a cv2.rectangle

Tags: python, opencv

I am using cv2.rectangles to attempt to draw a grid on an np.zeros window. I am looking for a way to use a for or while loop to automattically repeat the drawing of these lines (long thick rectangles) until the horizontal lines meet the bottom of the window and vertical lines the width.

I'd like for the algorithm to populate with rectangles of unchanging size/space between them, to the edges of any window size that is input. So the window would change size but the size of each grid line/square would not.

current code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#create np.zeros window
frame = np.zeros((600,600, 3), np.uint8)
width = frame.shape[0]
height = frame.shape[1]

#starting points for vertical line, #earlier while loop wouldn't let me use'<' with tuples
vertp1y = 25
vertp1x = 0
vertp2y = 35
vertp2x = height

#starting points for horizontal lines
horizp1y = 0
horizp1x = 25
horizp2y = width
horizp2x = 35

#pt1 and pt2 parameters set this way to attempting using as variables in later while loop
vert_line=cv2.rectangle(frame, (vertp1y, vertp1x), (vertp2y, vertp2x), (0,225,0), -1)
horiz_line=cv2.rectangle(frame, (horizp1y, horizp1x), (horizp2y, horizp2x), (0,225,0), -1)

while vertp2y < width:
    vertp1y = vertp1y + 25
    vertp2y = vertp2y + 25
    if vertp2y > width:
        break


cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when I run this I get no errors but the window with the two lines (rectangles) are returned unchanged.

I also attempted to use warpAffine translation using vert_line as the src, same issue, unchanged window returned.

```
M = np.float32([[-1,0,25], [0,1,0]])
vert_line_2 = cv2.warpAffine(vert_line, M, (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest option would be to draw the lines and columns instead of rectangles. To do this, you could try something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class BoxesDrawer:
    def __init__(self, box_size: tuple, border_size: int, color: tuple = (0, 255, 0)):
        self.box_size = box_size
        self.half_border_size = int(border_size // 2)
        self.color = color

    def draw_on(self, frame: np.asarray) -> np.asarray:
        self._draw_row(frame)
        self._draw_columns(frame)

        return frame

    def _draw_row(self, frame: np.asarray) -> np.asarray:
        row_size = self.box_size[0]

        index = 0
        while True:
            index += row_size
            if index > frame.shape[0]:
                break

            frame[index - self.half_border_size:index + self.half_border_size, :, :] = self.color
        return frame

    def _draw_columns(self, frame: np.asarray) -> np.asarray:
        column_size = self.box_size[1]

        index = 0
        while True:
            index += column_size
            if index > frame.shape[0]:
                break

            frame[:, index - self.half_border_size:index + self.half_border_size, :] = self.color
        return frame


if __name__ == '__main__':
    frame = np.zeros((224, 224, 3))

    drawer = BoxesDrawer(box_size=(20, 20), border_size=3, color=(0, 255, 0))
    drawer.draw_on(frame)

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(frame)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Not really a good looking code, though it should work for your use case. I'm 100% sure this could be optimized and you can even modify it to better fit your use case, but the baseline is here.

Comment: Solved, that was very fast! thank you so much!